# zip_iterator and lower_bound

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, lower-bound

I can't figure out how to call `lower_bound` with a `zip_iterator`.

This won't compile:

```
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void main()
{
    typedef int Key;
    typedef double Value;

    typedef boost::tuple<typename std::vector<Key>::iterator,
                         typename std::vector<Value>::iterator> the_iterator_tuple;
    typedef boost::zip_iterator<the_iterator_tuple> the_zip_iterator;

    std::vector<Key>   keys_;
    std::vector<Value> values_;

    // Add values to keys_ and values_...

    auto it = std::lower_bound(
        the_zip_iterator(the_iterator_tuple(keys_.begin(), values_.begin())),
        the_zip_iterator(the_iterator_tuple(keys_.end(), values_.end())),
        123,
        [](const the_iterator_tuple & it, const int v) -> bool { return *boost::get<0>(it) < v; }
    );

    // Use "it"...
}
```

VS2010 says it "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'const std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> &'" (plus several dozen other things for the same error), but it has to do with an obscure boost::tuple constructor, not with the given lambda.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::lower_bound(it, end, v)` needs to be able to do both `*it < v` and `v < *it`. Your function object supports only one of these.

Since there is a comment on this, leaving the above statement: This isn't the case. As Howard pointed out, the comparison is required to use `comp(*it, v)`, i.e., there is no need for this operation to be symmetric.

However, looking at the documentation of [`boost::zip_iterator<It0, It1>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) it seems that `*it` yields a `boost::tuple<typename It0::reference, typename It1::reference>`. Thus, adding the `typedef`

```
typedef boost::tuple<typename std::vector<Key>::reference,
                     typename std::vector<Value>::reference> the_reference_tuple;
```

... and changing the lambda to become

```
[](the_reference_tuple const& it, int v) { return it.get<0>() < v; }
```

solves the compilation issues using gcc and clang.

Comment: Nope. Just tried it to make sure. This compiels fine: `std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string>> ok; auto it = std::lower_bound(ok.begin(),ok.end(),123,[](const std::pair<int,std::string> & p, const int v) -> bool { return p.first < v; });`

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a "concepts checking" bug in VS2010.

25.4.3.1 [lower.bound]/p1:

> Requires:: The elements `e` of `[first,last)` shall be partitioned with
>   respect to the expression `e < value` or `comp(e, value)`.

I.e. only `*it < v` is required.

The `upper_bound` algorithm has the opposite requirement:  `v < *it`.  And `equal_range` requires both expressions to work.